# How do I change the text of a button on another screen in kivy (without kv lang)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to change the button text on another screen, but I don't use the kv language, how could I do that?
Here is a example of code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

list=['Yes','No']


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Iniciar(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Iniciar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.btn = Button(text='INICIAR', size_hint=(.2, .1), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'y': .05}, background_color=(0, 0, 1.60, 1),font_size=24, color=(.8, .9, 0, 1))
        self.btn.bind(on_press=self.press_button)
        self.add_widget(self.btn)

    def press_button(self, *args):
        list[0] = 'Apple'
        list[1] = 'Banana'
        self.manager.current = 'categorical'


class Categorical(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Categorical, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.button_1 = Button(text=list[0], size_hint=(.2, .1), pos_hint={'center_x': .35, 'y': .05})
        self.button_2 = Button(text=list[1], size_hint=(.2, .1), pos_hint={'center_x': .64, 'y': .05})
        self.add_widget(self.button_1)
        self.add_widget(self.button_2)

class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManagement(transition=FadeTransition())
        sm.add_widget(Iniciar(name='iniciar'))
        sm.add_widget(Categorical(name='categorical'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

In these case, I change the list that contain the values of the button texts

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use list for that. One simple way to do so is assign the button widget to a variable and use `button.text`. Like in your code you have assigned the Button widget to a variable named `self.button_1` and `self.button_2`. So to change the text of button_1 just do `self.button_1.text = 'new'` same for button_2, `self.button_2.text='new2'`

Answer (score 0):

`self.manager.get_screen('ScreenWithButton').ids['buttonid'].text = ""`